# Personal modules in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml, caml

I'm working on a school project that consists of handling a list of contact in OCaml. The thing is that we have to make modules but I'm not really sure to have understand how that works. I have an agenda.ml, agenda.mli, contact.ml and contact.mli but when I wanna use agenda.ml it says that Contact is an unbound value when I call a Contact.function even if I already did #use "contact.ml".

Could someone explain me that whole thingy of module please?

Comment: Please provide an example as small as possible with your 2 modules - and provide as well the compile command you are using (hopefully, use ocamlbuild)... Doing this will help you dig into modules - and will help the community to help you :) - Note that there is plenty of good documentation on the net (cf INRIA, Real World Ocaml, and : http://www.dicosmo.org/CourseNotes/pfav/1314/cours1.handout.pdf )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the toplevel, you need to use `#mod_use <filename>` rather than `#use <filename>`: `#use <filename>` simply reads the contents of the filename inside the current scope, whereas `#mod_use <filename>` use the file to define a new module `<Filename>` in the current scope.

However, both `#mod_use` and `#use` are simple textual directive that cannot work with pair of `ml` and `mli` files. You will need at some point to read on OCaml build system. For simple school project, ocamlbuild might be a good idea: compiling a whole project might be as simple as `ocamlbuild <main>.native`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working, it's enough for our tests for now but I'll have a look at that ocamlbuild later for sure!